# Implementing a JUnit test onto a Binary Search Tree that doesn't have an iterator?

Tags: java, junit, iterator, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've been working on implementing a JUnit test on a binary search tree that does not explicitly have an iterator. In place of an iterator this tree has a method called getNext() which, I would assume, in tandem with a while loop I could test the tree without errors in the test. The problem is that I am not sure how to implement the while loop into my tests to get my tests to work.

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements 
BSTInterface<T> {
protected BSTNode<T> root;

boolean found;

protected LinkedUnbndQueue<T> inOrderQueue; // queue of info
protected LinkedUnbndQueue<T> preOrderQueue; // queue of info
protected LinkedUnbndQueue<T> postOrderQueue; // queue of info

public BinarySearchTree()
{
    root = null;
}

private T recGet(T element, BSTNode<T> tree)
{
    if (tree == null)
        return null; // element is not found
    else if (element.compareTo(tree.getInfo()) < 0)
        return recGet(element, tree.getLeft()); // get from left subtree
    else if (element.compareTo(tree.getInfo()) > 0)
        return recGet(element, tree.getRight()); // get from right subtree
    else
        return tree.getInfo(); // element is found
}

public T get(T element)
// Returns an element e from this BST such that e.compareTo(element) == 0;
// if no such element exists, returns null.
{
    return recGet(element, root);
}

private T getPredecessor(BSTNode<T> tree)
// Returns the information held in the rightmost node in tree
{
    while (tree.getRight() != null)
        tree = tree.getRight();
    return tree.getInfo();
}

private void inOrder(BSTNode<T> tree)
// Initializes inOrderQueue with tree elements in inOrder order.
{
    if (tree != null) {
        inOrder(tree.getLeft());
        inOrderQueue.enqueue(tree.getInfo());
        inOrder(tree.getRight());
    }
}

private void preOrder(BSTNode<T> tree)
// Initializes preOrderQueue with tree elements in preOrder order.
{
    if (tree != null) {
        preOrderQueue.enqueue(tree.getInfo());
        preOrder(tree.getLeft());
        preOrder(tree.getRight());
    }
}

private void postOrder(BSTNode<T> tree)
// Initializes postOrderQueue with tree elements in postOrder order.
{
    if (tree != null) {
        postOrder(tree.getLeft());
        postOrder(tree.getRight());
        postOrderQueue.enqueue(tree.getInfo());
    }
}

public T getNext(int orderType)
{
    if (orderType == INORDER)
        return inOrderQueue.dequeue();
    else if (orderType == PREORDER)
        return preOrderQueue.dequeue();
    else if (orderType == POSTORDER)
        return postOrderQueue.dequeue();
    else
        return null;
}
```

I've removed the usual add, remove, and contains methods from the tree to save space. The tests I am running utilize TestCase and a TestRunner. What I have for tests so far are just simple add, remove, size, and contains tests. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to test `getNext`? Calling it returns a `LinkedUnbndQueue`. What is `LinkedUnbndQueue`. Why not assert the content by calling methods on `LinkedUnbndQueue`?

Comment: @user7 No, I am trying to get any test to work with the tree. My question pertains on how to get the tests to run. Because this tree does not explicitly have an iterator, I am having troubles with figuring it out, but I believe I need to use the getNext method and a while loop in the test class to have it act as an iterator, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What does happen when `LinkedUnbndQueue.dequeue` is called after all elements are exhausted. Will it keep returning null?

Comment: @user7 It will keep returning null, but the user ends the program when it is finished. The programs that utilize this search tree are built around user input, which makes tests a little more difficult, especially when I'm still learning how to use JUnit effectively.

Answer (score 0):

After constructing the tree, you would have an object of type `BinarySearchTree<SomeType>` in your tests.

Then you can call `getNext` till it returns null (as you have said in the comments)

```
BinarySearchTree<SomeType> tree;
...
SomeType data;
while ((data = tree.getNext()) != null) {
    //do whatever assertion you want to do with the returned data.
}
```

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand your need correctly. I'm happy to refine based on your inputs/comments